How long would Blood Antarctica last?
I have an alien terraforming a barren Earth into a corpse world. One of its project is transforming Antarctica by slowly replacing all the ice with frozen blood. It extracts the blood from countless human corpses, freezes it into a solid, and then finally replaces the Antarctic ice with the frozen blood. Eventually, this should extend to every ice, glacier, ice sheet, etc. to turn Antarctica into Blood Antarctica.
It intends for Blood Antarctica to last on its own for a very long time without requiring outside interference, a millennium at a minimum. It hopes that Antarctica's coldness could keep the blood ice unmelted. As long as 80% of it as a whole remains frozen, the alien would consider it adequate. How long would Blood Antarctica truly last?

Blood in one human: 4-6 L. Ice in Antarctica: 30 billion billion L. That may take awhile.

Under the assumption that it can be done (which would indeed require a very large human-grinder), you might want to add what stands in the way of a simple “yes” answer. Is there a specific property of blood that means that it wouldn’t ordinarily freeze at subzero temperatures/under the conditions you describe?

@controlgroup Changed the question

notably, blood is darker than water ice (citation needed), and so will reflect less sunlight - meaning it absorbs more, warming up more strongly than regular antarctic ice would. At the very least, your alien is speeding up the melting of antarctica's ice by replacing it with darker blood. plus, decay processes often release heat too - so any molten blood will produce more warmth, although probably only a bit.

@Cadence I'm now starting to wonder even if you collected every last drop of blood in all of human history (so imagine every person on earth donating as much as they can for as long as they can throughout their life) whether that would be enough to replace all the water ice in Antarctica. I'm guessing not even close.

@Crazymoomin 117 billion humans ever, current global life expectancy is 73.16 years, half a litre is typically donated at a time, blood volume is replaced in 24 hours after donation but red blood cells take 4 weeks, so 13 donations per year. So 111,277 billion litres or 3,115,759 billion litres if we're okay with watery blood. So at max we have 3,116 cubic kilometres of blood and Antarctica has 26.5 million cubic kilometres of ice. If you add the ~5L of blood people have when they die that's another 585 cubic kilometres.

@SamDean I guess you could add an extra 6 liters per person when they die and you suck them dry, but that's clearly not going to make any significant difference.

Sorry numbers are off (I missed a multiplication sign so had 0.513 instead of 0.5*13).
55,638 billion litres of blood, 1,557,869 billion litres of watery blood, so 1,558 cubic kilometres of blood. 26.5 million cubic kilometres of ice, is correct.
Conversion for blood on death is out by a factor of 10, it's only 0.585 cubic kilometres.

Only pure water freezes, true of the ocean, true of blood too.

@Dmyt, I assume this Q is a continuation of your hivemind world and this previous question. If so, it's worth linking that question periodically to remind people of the scale you're working with, because 444,444,444,444 is a lot of people - although it's still unlikely to be enough to completely cover Antarctica in blood.

BTW, as you work though this, bear in mind that displacing the ice covering Antarctica to replace it with blood would have a serious consequence on the oceans, their depth and their currents. Whatever answers you receive here you're going to be stuck with making a choice based on narrative necessity because predicting those climactic changes is out of scope for the site (Book Rule), if they can be predicted at all. I.E., so much changes that the answer can be anything you want and no one can challenge you.

Matter frozen into ice can last many thousands of years.  Ice cores can be 800,000 years old or easily more, and preserve the conditions of the ice laid down at that time.
However, while deep ice would likely remain unchanged for a great many thousand years, the surface ice exposed to oxygen and light may well slowly decay, changing from blood-red to rust-brown over a matter of mere months or years, though given the low temperatures, this would likely take longer than a bloodstain at room temperature.
So, we can expect that after a while, the exposed blood-ice would turn visibly brown, though when the blood-ice breaks, it would expose blood-red broken surfaces.

I imagine the outside of a glacier entirely dried over, only for a crack to form and the glacier starts bleeding, literally.

Adding pressure (by stacking more ice on top) increases temperature. Increasing temperature melts the solution. Low ambient temperature cools it down again slowly. The most freezable regions of the solution (dead cells and thermodynamically random regions of more pure water) precipitate out. Since ice is lighter than saltwater they float to the surface, while the heavier organics (dead cells and such) sink. You'll get a salty mud layer under an water ice layer under a thin layer of frozen blood.

There’s a lot of justification missing here. Just from step 1 to 2: how do you know the ice pressure increases the temperature enough to melt the solution?

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine The specifics may be off, but in the northern ice sheet it's a fairly well-known phenomenon that there is enough temperature fluctuation to slowly purify the ice, even if it it never fully melts in significant quantities. So it's at least going to be a factor in how long the original description of what is being created can last without outside intervention.

Would this separate the blood cells from the plasma, or would this go even further?
